# Storing FILE data in a session for later use move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, mysql, session

I dont know if this is possible but I need to store the FILE data into a session so I can in the future uses its information to store images into the server.

At the moment the drag and drop is storing data to the server straight way.

Basically I have a form where user can fill in information of the product and then add images. once user enters enters required information and press submit, those information will then be stored into mysql where a product ID is created. with that product key I would use it to name the images such as **product_ID + product_namme + image number.jpg** The problem is I cant find a way to store the FILE data up to this point, I have tried using session, but when I echo its value its blank.

PHP
This version works but store the data straight way so i cant rename the file. This is happening before

```
foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $position => $name){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$position], '../ProductImages/'.$name));
}
```

This is the code with session in it, however when I echo those sessions after user has pressed submited, they are blank. If I echo just below this code it will have data. Is there something Im missing?

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'][0])){
    $_SESSION['imgAmount'] = 1;
    foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $position){
        $_SESSION['tmpVal'][$position] = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$position];
        $_SESSION['imgAmount']++;
    }
}
```

This is where the seesion is called

```
$i = 0;
 if(isset($_SESSION['tmpVal'])){
        while($i < $_SESSION['imgAmount']){
            move_uploaded_file($_SESSION['tmpVal'][$i],'../ProductImages/'.$imgID . 'child' . $i . '.jpg');
            $i++;
            echo "test0";
            echo "<br>" . $_SESSION ['tmpVal'];
            echo "<br>" . $_SESSION ['imgAmount'];
            echo "<br>" . $_SESSION ['tmpVal'][0];
            echo "<br>" . $_SESSION ['tmpVal'][1];

        }
    }
```

Comment: The information in that array is of temporary use only. It makes absolutely no sense to store it in a session. Save those aspects you need into your database, move the temporary file to the final destination. For that you should _not_ use the client provided filename! That is a security gap! Instead generate an internal file name along the approach you yourself sketched. Just change the way you concatenate the target path in your call to `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way. Make the drag'n'drop _not_ auto upload the file and post it with the rest of the information instead + what the previous comment says about security. If the file is large, the upload might not even be complete when the user submits the form.

Comment: I thought about moving it to the database the temporary files, and once I store all the others information from the user to the database, get the product_ID and store it again with the actual product data. But I though storing temporary data on the database is not really that efficient as I will have to keep transferring data, wont that slow down the connection?

Comment: And about the client filename yes I know that I only kept there for example purpose only thats not the final work.

Comment: Storing files in the database doesn't make any sense. You could just store them in a temporary folder instead. But really, why _first_ upload the image and _then_ post the form? What if the user doesn't post the form at all? Or changes his/her mind and upload another image instead?
 Then you'll have unused, uploaded images that's just taking space. Why not just post everything together?

Comment: I dont want to post everything together because posting the images is not require, which is why i want to store in a temporary file first to validate what u just mentioned. But i dont know how to store in a temporary folder as I mentioned the session cookies are not keeping the files information.

Comment: How would posting it together require them to upload an image? When the form is posted, store the info in your DB, get the ID and if the post contains an image, handle the upload. If not, no worries...

Comment: Its a drag and drop base system. once the images are dragged they automatically call the ondrag function which is then processed to upload it with the move_uploaded function. This happens before the form is submit therefore there is no ID to get from the database. what I want to do is drag and drop save store the files data, user finished filling in information on the page press submit button, all information is stored on the database, get ID from the database, call move_upload function store images to its location with name ID+something.jpg store image name to mysql database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149206/discussion-between-luke-ds-and-magnus-eriksson).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot store files into sessions and use them later

I have implemented the below code in 1 of my projects in which I save the files to 1 location and then on a condition been met I copy them to the actual target location and delete from the temporary location

```
//Initial storing
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++)
        {
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][ $i ] == 0)
            {
                $tmpName = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][ $i ];
                $name = $_FILES['files']['name'][ $i ];
                $location = "temp/";

                move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $location . $name);
            }
        }
session(['filesList' => $_FILES]);

//Final moving to the actual target location

$fileList = session('filesList');
if (count($fileList['files']['name']) > 0)
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($fileList['files']['name']); $i++)
            {
                if ($fileList['files']['error'][ $i ] == 0)
                {
                    $name = $fileList['files']['name'][ $i ];

                    $transferFile = "temp/" . $name;

                    $location[] = "files/" . $userId . $name;

                    copy($transferFile, $location[ $i ]);
                    unlink('temp/' . $name);
                }
            }
        }
```

so basically except the session code which is in laravel you can use the rest of the code in core PHP as well

Hope this helps

Comment: where is function `session()` defined?

Comment: this is laravel's way of defining a session , but you can use $_SESSION in its place